Unable to get local issuer certificate error on publish to IOT topic via AWS IOT endpoint on aws-sdk v3 javascript module IOTDataPlaneClient
I am getting error :  UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY when trying to publish to topic through IOT endpoint.  I am using amazon root ca 1 cert and also used certs mentioned here https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/issues/240
Code :     Please guide how to resolve this issue and where I am going wrong.
import { IoTDataPlaneClient, PublishCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-iot-data-plane";
import https from 'https';
import { NodeHttpHandler } from "@smithy/node-http-handler";

const run = async () => {
  try {
    const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
      ca: '----BEGIN--- AMAZON ROOT CA CERT ---END---',  // Amazon Root CA downloaded from https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/issues/240
    });

    const client = new IoTDataPlaneClient({
      region: "us-east-1",
      endpoint: `https://<endpoint>`,
      requestHandler: new NodeHttpHandler({
        httpsAgent,
      }),
    });

    const params = {
      topic: "my/topic",
      payload: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ message: "Hello Message!" })),
      qos: 0,
    };

    const data = await client.send(new PublishCommand(params));
    console.log("Message published:", data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error publishing message:", err);
  }
};

run();

I am using amazon root ca 1 cert and also used certs mentioned here https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/issues/240  But issue is not resolved.
Thanks.
